# Javascript reset loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a little problem with my javascript code,
i build a function that add filed by a qty that the user choose,
here is the function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qty').change(function(){
     for (var i=0;i<$('.qty').val();i++){
       $('.append').append('<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>');
     }
  });
});
```

AND the html code is:

```
<select name="qty" class="qty">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div class="append">

</div>
```

when i pick a value in the qty, lets say 3, it open me up 3 select fields, but when i change the selection to 2, it adds me 2, so i have 5 select fileds, how do i reset? if i pick 1 it will open me 1 and if i change it to 2 it will change and open me 2 not 3 like it is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qty').change(function(){
    var html=''
     for (var i=0;i< parseInt($('.qty').val());i++){
       html += '<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>';
     }
     $('.append').html(html);
  });
});
```

Comment: Removes the select the user have already made (if any have already been made) which might be perfectly valid according to OP. that aside it's a definite improvement to change the DOM just once instead of in every loop

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the `.append` div contents prior to appending, you can clear it with [`.html('')`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), so you just need to replace your following line:

```
$('.append').append('<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>');
```

for this one:

```
$('.append').html('').append('<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>');
```

Comment: By clearing the html you are also clearing all selections the user might already have made. Sure it's not a requirement in OP but would lead to annoying UX I guess

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qty').change(function(){
      var k=""   
      for (var i=0;i<$('.qty').val();i++){
          k += '<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>';
     }
     $('.append').html(k);
  });
});​
```

here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P2F9x/

Comment: perhaps it is (didn't state it was wrong) but it will yield a strange UX

Comment: Yea you're right didnt understand what you meant in the start

Answer (score 1):

You could add one line to empty the append div before the loop

```
$('.append').empty();
```

so it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qty').change(function(){
     $('.append').empty();
     for (var i=0;i<$('.qty').val();i++){
       $('.append').append('<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>');
     }
  });
});​
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('.append').append('<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>');
```

Use

```
$('.append').html('<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>');
```

I think that is what is causing it to append the additional fields.

Comment: that only insert one element (or to be more precise any element inserted except the last will be overridden)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it through, I would of added the selects to a variable then used $('.append').html pretty much as the solutions above show. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to reset html:

```
$('.append').html('');
```

like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qty').change(function(){
    $('.append').html('');
     for (var i=0;i<$('.qty').val();i++){
       $('.append').append('<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>');
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve any selections the user have already made you could change the structue somewhat

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qty').change(function(){
     var count = $(.append).find("select").length,
         qty = $('.qty').val(),
         i,
         html = $('.append').html();
     //append any needed elements
     if(count < qty) {
       for (i=count;i < qty; i += 1){
         html += '<select name="data[]"><option value="one">1</option></select>';
       }
       $('.append').html(html);
     }
     //remove any excess elements
     for(;count<$(.append).find("select").length; 
          $(.append).find("select:last").remove()){}
  });
});
```